# Mysql объединение таблиц и вывод поля если совпали ID между ними

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть 2 таблицы.

1. rent
2. rent_photo

Таблица rent содерижт поле (id).

Таблица rent_photo содержит поле (id, rent_id, photo).

**Задача:**

Чтобы при совпадении поля id из таблицы rent и поля rent_id из таблицы rent_photo показывалось содержимое поля photo из таблицы rent_photo.

**Важные дополнения:**

Нам нужно рандомно выбирать 1 фото для каждого id, фото на одно id может быть и 20, но нам нужно 1 значение для каждого поля.

Привожу также PHP цикл, в котором выводится информация и команды Mysql.

В коде PHP используется Redbean PHP.

```
    <?php if (isset($top3)): ?>
<div id='Description'>
<div class="main">

<!--Колонки-->
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($top3 as $id => $ads): ?>
  <div class="column">
      <a href="ads/rent/<?=$id;?>">
    <div class="content">
         <h3><?= isset($ads['title']) ? $ads['title'] : null; ?></h3>



      <?php if (isset($ads['img'])): ?>
                    <img src="./Download_Rent/<?= $ads['img']; ?>"  width="100%" height="100%">




                            <?php else: ?>
                                <img src="./Photo/No photo.jpg">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                                              
    <h3>Цена: <?= number_format($ads['price'], 0, '.', '.'); ?> Р.</h3>
               
                      <button class="PreviewButton">Подробнее...</button>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?> 
</div>
<!--Конец колонок-->
</div>
<!--Конец центрирования блока объявлений-->
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Уточните задачу. Понятно, что для rent, имеющих photo, надо вывести одно случайное photo. А что делать с теми, у кого photo нет вообще ни одного? И - Вы хотите на PHP в цикле для каждого отдельного rent получить photo и вывести, или хотите сразу одним запросом получить все rent и соответствующие photo, а потом выводить в цикле?

Comment: @Akina Добрый день, спасибо за отклик. Все просто, в PHP команде стоит else где если нет фото, выводится фотография с надписью "Нет фото". В начале конечно идет команда Mysql где получаем все записи, а уже из полученных данных мы формируем цикл.

Comment: С первым вопросом понятно. Но он не так и важен. Что со вторым вопросом?

Comment: @Akina  если вам не затруднит, можно оба варианта подсказать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что то в таком духе:

`SELECT photo FROM rent, rent_photo WHERE rent.id=rent_photo.rent_id`

Можно еще через inner join сделать, но для начала это го должно хватить

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению в контексте PHP цикла foreach данная команда не сработала(( Суть команды вывод URL ссылки на картинку.

Comment: А если выполнить этот запрос из чего то вроде mysql workbench - получается нужный результат? Может, просто в php неправильно обрабатывается вывод данных из запроса? Ошибка в PHP какая то конкретная есть?

Comment: Я использую также RedBean PHP. Уже создал тему и подробно ее описал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1175303/php-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-foreach-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-mysql                      Если есть возможность, очень прошу помочь, над этим вопросом уже 2 недели мучаюсь...

Comment: я прочитал тему, мне кажется, вы что то делаете не так. Скорее всего, последовательность решения должна быть такой: сначала выполнить запрос в mysql workbench или php admin. Как только запрос заработает - перенести его в php. Про ORM - забыть, он Вам только мешает. Можете также в этот запрос добавитьвесь php файл, в котрый вы вставляете запрос - может, там какая то проблема

Comment: Забыл очень важный момент в этой теме указать, это что фото на каждый id должно выводиться рандомно в количестве 1 штуки, если ставлю так    $img = R::getAssoc('SELECT photo FROM rent, rent_photo WHERE rent.id = ? LIMIT 1' rent_photo.rent_id'); выходит ошибка, знаю что запрос неверный, но пока не освоился в Mysql. Кстати вашу команду которую написали вначале я прогнал по var_dump и все поля photo в ней массивом вывелись как и должны быть, вот только почему эти же данные в <a href не вносятся??? Может потому-что пока ограничение в 1 рандомное фото не установили?

Comment: Вот 2 команды на странице из которых работает цикл.  
                                                                                                                                                           
$top3 = R::getAssoc('SELECT id, town_sell, year, run, mark, model, price, description FROM rent ORDER BY time_upload DESC');
  
Ваша команда    $img = R::getAssoc('SELECT photo FROM rent, rent_photo WHERE rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id');         Нужно в команде Mysql  с полем photo установить чтобы на id выводилось рандомно лишь 1 фотография, подскажите как заменить? .

Comment: Ваш исходный вопрос можно дополнить. Допишите туда код, вполне возможно, кто то кроме меня подскажет. Хорошо, что sql запрос работает, переложить его на php - уже не очень сложная задача

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендации, дополнил вопрос. PHP код собран, единственная ошибка сейчас - это команда Mysql.

Comment: А, может быть, вы добавите в вопрос Ваш php-код? Просто теперь, когда sql запрос уже работает, нужно написать на php правильнео обращение к базе. Наверное, если Ваш код будет в вопросе - то кто нибудь сможет Ваш код подкорректировать.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, добавил.

Comment: Пока-что это самый близкий к ответу скрипт, но задача еще не решена.

Answer (score 2):

> можно оба варианта подсказать?

Вариант, когда цикл перебора записей `rent` организован в PHP, MySQL возвращает одну запись для каждого заданного `rent.id`, передаваемый как параметр из переменной `$rent_id`. Предполагается, что `rent_photo.photo` содержит имя и путь к файлу с фотографией, а имя файла с путём, который выводится при отсутствии фотографий, передаётся как параметр из переменной `$no_photo_file`.

```
SELECT rent.id, COALESCE(rent_photo.photo, '$no_photo_file') filepath_to_photo
FROM rent
LEFT JOIN rent_photo ON rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id
WHERE rent.id = $rent_id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Вариант, когда MySQL возвращает все `rent`, а потом PHP выполняет цикл перебора полученного набора для вывода.

```
SELECT rent.id,
       COALESCE( ( SELECT rent_photo.photo 
                   FROM rent_photo 
                   WHERE rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id
                   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ), 
                 '$no_photo_file') filepath_to_photo
FROM rent
```

Одинарные кавычки, обрамляющие литерал, должны присутствовать в значении PHP-переменной, в которой будет формироваться текст запроса, так что они должны быть соответствующим образом экранированы.

Comment: Обе команды не работают. syntax error, unexpected 'filepath' (T_STRING), expecting ')'  Можно код без строчки filepath ???

Comment: Уточню вопрос, к примеру у нас в базе 100 полей id. В каждом поле id может быть 5 записей photo, к примеру photo записей 500 штук. Нам нужно вывести все 100 записей id и только 100 фото. То есть 1 к 1, а не 100 id и 500 фото.

Comment: @Eric7777777 *Обе команды не работают. syntax error, unexpected 'filepath' (T_STRING), expecting ')'* o_O А вставить туда путь и имя файла, который *фотография с надписью "Нет фото"* - не догадался??? Не говоря уж о том, что сообщение об ошибке - типично пэхапэшное (не MySQL), и оно намекает, что кто-то тупо вставил текст в переменную, не озаботившись квотированием кавычек.

Comment: Mysql не изучал поэтому такие и ошибки,  сейчас подставил такую вариацию. $img = R::getAssoc('SELECT rent.id,
       COALESCE( ( SELECT rent_photo.photo 
                   FROM rent_photo 
                   WHERE rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id
                   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ), 
                 'Download_Rent/No photo.jpg') Download_Rent/No photo.jpg
FROM rent');
выводит ошибку.  Путь к фото Download_Rent/No photo.jpg    Буду признателен за корректную команду, хоят понимаю что ошибки просто супер банальные.

Comment: Сделал вот так, тоже не работает((    SELECT rent.id, COALESCE(rent_photo.photo, 'Download_Rent "Нет фото"') Download_Rent/No photo.jpg
FROM rent
LEFT JOIN rent_photo ON rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id
WHERE rent.id = $rent_id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Comment: @Eric7777777 Вообще-то изменять надо текст в литерале, а не его алиас. И путь должен быть абсолютным. И кавычки вокруг литерала надо не удалить, а квотировать. MySQL Вы не изучали, может быть - но PHP-то изучали!

Comment: Нужно итоговое решение.  Я и так 2 недели сижу с этой командой, весь интернет прогуглил, сон к нулю и нервы тоже.

Comment: @Eric7777777 Поправил ответ. Если и этого недостаточно - я не знаю, как уже Вам объяснять.

Comment: Господа, я предлагаю Вам как бы немного понизить градус дискуссии, ведь это всего лишь программирование :-) Что я вижу: я вижу сильную смесь html с php кодом, уже это модет вызывать некоторые проблемы. Одна кавычка пропущена - и мы получим ошибку. Может, в качестве промежуточного решения задачи автор вопроса напишет "чистый php скрипт", который просто достаёт нужную инфу из mysql и печатает её текстом? когда это заработает - туда можно будет добавить разных html тегов...

Comment: @Akina   Я также использую RedBeanphp моя команда выглядит так                     
$img = R::getAssoc('SELECT rent.id, COALESCE(rent_photo.photo, '$no_photo_file') Download_Rent/No photo.jpg
  FROM rent
      LEFT JOIN rent_photo ON rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id
          WHERE rent.id = $rent_id
               ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');                                                               
  Может кому-то будет смешно, но для меня это 2 недели с 0 настроением. Код также не работает.

Comment: @S.H. Возможно, но когда стоит вопрос личных финансов, нервов, отсутствия сна , настроения и  бесконечного просмотра ошибок чтобы ты не менял "просто программированием" оно быть перестает. Как я и говорил, ваша команда выводит все адреса фото правильно, но задачу я уточнил, нужно 1 фото на 1 id  независимо от кол-ва фото в поле photo. Вопрос до сих пор не решен. Sql команд я не знаю.

Comment: @Eric7777777 Бесполезно спрашивать меня, как правильно использовать показанный запрос в RedBean, про который я знаю лишь, что он существует. Почти бесполезно - про то же в PHP, я его не использую, и сказал уже практически всё, что знаю. Но если Вы не понимаете простейших терминов "квотирование" и "экранирование" по отношению к спецсимволам в строковых литералах - видимо, Вы в них понимаете ещё меньше, чем я? Думаю, Вам имеет смысл создать отдельный вопрос типа "есть текст SQL-запроса, как его правильно выполнить в PHP/RedBeans и получить результат его выполнения".

Comment: Парни, мы все (метафорически) в одной лодке, я вот тоже с понедельнка пытаюсь научиться из c++ кода отправлять письмо... Смотрите. Вам ваш RedBean только мешает. Задача - простейшая: "есть sql запрос, как его выполнить из PHP?". Пусть запрос вернет вам все фото. Потом, уже в php, можно выбрать одну случайную фотку. Можно создать еще один вопрос на этом сайте. можно погуглить. Можно найти пример с другим запросом и попытаться скрестить его с Вашим кодом

Comment: @S.H.  Спасибо в любом случае всем кто пытался помочь. Вам успешно разобраться с отправкой. Я создал новую тему с RedBean.

Comment: Вам RedBean только мешает. Он вносит еще одну неопределенность, еще одно место, где может возникать ошибка. Забудьте про него. Вот здесь есть примеры того, как создать подключение к базе и вытащить из неё набор данных: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php